# Finding a blog site with good code block support

Tags: hosting, blogs

This has probably been asked before but I can't find any relevant post using the search system.

I'm looking for a site where I could host my own blog. Unfortunately, I found none that have the kind of code block friendliness found on our very own stackoverflow (not one where you have to manually convert < and > into `&lt;` and `&gt;`).

If the answer is "there is none, duh!", and I am condemned to install my own blog software, then which one should I use for a "coder blog" -- knowing that I'd like it to be ultra-simple to set up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a combination of [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/), Windows Live Writer and a WLW extension to format/place the code block in my blog.

Scott Hanselman has a blog post about this topic [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx).

There is a pretty sweet client-side (jQuery-based) code formatter here that you also [might want to check out](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/), that sounds blog-software agnostic.

Comment: I have no experience in .NET whatsoever but the jQuery plugin looks nice :)

Comment: I went for something hosted on blogspot and used the plugin there ;)

And yes, I know, I'm slow at accepting answers :P

Answer (score 2):

I use appengine and [bloog](http://bloog.billkatz.com/) mostly because of this feature (and because I can extend it anyway I want). The good thing is it's relatively easy to set up and free. If your blog makes enough traffic to go over the limit for free accounts chances are you can get your money back from it.

Comment: Isn't it a bit "over the top" for a simple blog? (just asking)

Comment: Not really. The code was written already and deploying applications on appengine is as easy (if not easier) as getting a wordpress blog up.

Comment: Sounds nice but I admit I'm a bit lost in front of the wall of text. Is there some kind of simple tutorial somewhere?

Comment: The code is here http://github.com/DocSavage/bloog/tree/master. The settings are pretty obvious in config.py. Deployment info can be found here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html you need to open an account on appengine and use the sdk to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I was pulling my hair out trying to format code on Blogger until I found [this handy utility](http://formatmysourcecode.blogspot.com/).  It's not a perfect solution, but it goes a long way.

Comment: Definitely not the kind of workaround I'm looking for. I tried similar solutions and it always messed up with wysiwyg editors... maybe I did it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This css script might be useful to all - It is not for syntax highlighting but works well for presenting the source code in original format :

```
 <pre style="font-family: Andale Mono, Lucida Console, Monaco, fixed, monospace; 
                color: #000000; background-color: #eee;
                font-size: 12px; border: 1px dashed #999999;
                line-height: 14px; padding: 5px; 
                overflow: auto; width: 100%">
       <code style="color:#000000;word-wrap:normal;">

            <<<<<<<YOUR CODE HERE>>>>>>>

       </code>
 </pre>
```

**How to use :**

1. Paste this snippet in text editor,
2. paste your code in <<<<<<>>>>>> block.
3. Copy all and
4. paste to HTML view in blogger(or any other) post editor.

**BENEFITS :** Simple and easy to use, less configuration, easy to reconfigure, no extra software